# Which response code for resources max. limit in REST API?

Tags: rest, http, post, httpresponse, http-response-codes

I am designing a REST API for registering enrollments to classes. In my of my endpoints, I can `POST` an enrollment:

```
POST to http://my-api/class/learn-rest/enrollment
```

This creates a new enrollment. However, in this case, there can only be a fixed number of enrollments, let's say 5.

Which HTTP response code should I return when the user tries to add the 6th enrollment?

Answer (score 3):

Good question. Not sure why it's down-voted.

I'd suggest 400. It's the one you should use if you can't find a specific and appropriate status code for your 4xx errors.

- 409: it's inappropriate because it's usually retriable. But certainly retrying in your case would resolve the problem.
- 429: it's also retriable.

Did more research (some practices used by well-known api providers)

> LimitExceededException: Returned if the request results in one of the following limits being exceeded, a vault limit, a tags limit, or the provisioned capacity limit.    400 Bad Request

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/api-error-responses.html

> Unless a more specific error status is appropriate for the given request, services SHOULD return "400 Bad Request" and an error payload conforming to the error response guidance provided in the Microsoft REST API Guidelines.

https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/Guidelines.md#1521-error-response

Comment: 400 is appropriate as a generic client error here, though 409 may be a more appropriate specific error to use to represent a conflict with the existing state. Regarding whether it is retriable, it _is_ possible that the conflict may be resolvable by the caller if they delete one of the resources first and then retry.

Answer (score 1):

While suggesting some specific HTTP code may be an opinion based answer, there is one things that you should keep in mind - this is should be a [4xx Client error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes):

> 4xx Client errors: This class of status code is intended for situations in which the error seems to have been caused by the client.

Among existing errors, the following looks like the most suitable for you:

- 409 Conflict: Indicates that the request could not be processed because of conflict in the request, such as an edit conflict between multiple simultaneous updates.

I think so cause there is a next possible scenario: let's say you set 5 as the limit of enrollments, 4 already exist in system and server receives 2 requests at the same time to create a new enrollment. In this case, only one of the requests (the first one for server) is OK.

Comment: +1 to 409, although 400 would be perfectly acceptable as well as a generic client error. Although 409 is often used for versioning/concurrency conflicts, it seems appropriate for this use case as well meeting the [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) definition that "the request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target resource."